# Fragment based Tabs without ActionBar

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments, android-tabhost

Google's [FragmentTabs demo](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabs.html) feels very hackish to me. Does anyone know a nice way to have fragment based tabs that do not rely on the ActionBar?

The ActionBar is not an option, because the tabs must appear somewhere else on the screen. Also, the ActionBar lacks in the support library.

Just wanted to check before I go on and build my own solution...

Answer (score 1):

I used this implementation in my app and it works great. It does not require an ActionBar and uses Fragments with a ViewPager. I came across this if anyone is still interested...

[SwipeyTabs](http://code.google.com/p/android-playground/source/browse/#svn/trunk/SwipeyTabsSample)

Also here is a blog post about it:

http://blog.peterkuterna.net/2011/09/viewpager-meets-swipey-tabs.html

Answer (score 0):

[TabActivity in the Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html)
has an example using fragments and the TabHost and TabWidget. Hope this helps.